# Find if min-heap has k smaller elements than query

Tags: algorithm, heap, time-complexity

I've been scratching my head for a long time thinking about this. I need to find an O(k) algorithm to find if a min-heap has `k` smaller elements than a query `q`.

I've tried a recursive algorithm such as this:

```
count = 0;
def kSmaller(H, q, k){
   if (root(H) == Null or root(H) >= q ) return;
   else {count++;
         if (count == k) return true;
         kSmaller(LeftChild(root(H), q, k)
         kSmaller(RightChild(root(H), q, k)
    }
}
```

But after going through some min-heap examples I couldn't quite understand how I can terminate in O(k) time instead of going through every element unnecessarily.

Can anyone please help me understand how to approach this? Perhaps it's best to not use recursion and to flatten the solution out instead.

Answer (score 2):

A Min heap is arranged in the way that each node is smaller than all of the nodes in both it's subtrees. Hence your code would take O(k) time, as you cut out the recursion when you see a node greater than or equal to q value. You could draw a few examples and see. If the Min heap had p nodes less than q, then you would take min(p,k) time only, can you see that?

Comment: Right, that's just because of how min heaps are structured.

Comment: A general question having to do with my code. If I return 'true' inside a level of my recursion, does it return true for the whole function or does it just go back up to the level of recursion above it?

Comment: @MarksCode: The true is returned to previous level of recursion. You may want to modify your code to handle the values returned by recursive calls of subproblems.

Comment: Hmm Ok, I understand the going back up a level of recursion but as far as modifying to handle the values returned I don't exactly get what you mean but I'll think of it some more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that this algorithm is in fact O(k) time is this:

Let all nodes initially be white.  Colour a node black if it is visited by a call to `kSmaller()` that increments `count`, and grey if it is visited by a call to `kSmaller()` that doesn't increment `count`.  Recursion halts when `count` doesn't get incremented, so every node beneath a grey node is necessarily white; OTOH, every child of a black node must be either black or grey.  Clearly there are exactly `count` black nodes, and since every node has at most 2 children, it follows that there can be at most `count * 2` grey nodes, so there can be at most `count * 3` visited (i.e., black or grey) nodes overall.  Since `count` clearly always remains <= k, no more than 3k nodes are ever visited.  Finally, since only O(1) work is done by each call (outside of time spent in recursive calls), the overall time complexity is at worst O(k).